# Fixing Python code which includes dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Use a dictionary to count the frequency of numbers in the given “text” string. Only numbers should be counted. Do not count blank spaces, letters, or punctuation. Complete the function so that input like "1001000111101" will return a dictionary that holds the count of each number that occurs in the string  {'1': 7, '0': 6}. This function should:

1. accept a string “text” variable through the function’s parameters;
2. initialize a new dictionary;
3. iterate over each text character to check if the character is a number;
4. count the frequency of numbers in the input string, ignoring all other characters;
5. populate the new dictionary with the numbers as keys, ensuring each key is unique, and assign the value for each key with the count of that number;
6. return the new dictionary.

```html
def count_numbers(text):
    # Initialize a new dictionary.
    dictionary = {}
    # Complete the for loop to iterate through each "text" character.
    for i in text:
        # Complete the if-statement using a string method to check if the
        # character is a number.
        if i == int:

            # Complete the if-statement using a logical operator to check if
            # the number is not already in the dictionary.
            if i in dictionary:

                # Use a dictionary operation to add the number as a key
                # and set the initial count value to zero.
                    dictionary.update({text, i})
            # Use a dictionary operation to increment the number count value
            # for the existing key.
            i += i
    return dictionary

print(count_numbers("1001000111101"))
# Should be {'1': 7, '0': 6}

print(count_numbers("Math is fun! 2+2=4"))
# Should be {'2': 2, '4': 1}

print(count_numbers("This is a sentence."))
# Should be {}

print(count_numbers("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should be {'5': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't complete your assignment for you (because then you won't learn anything), but I'll offer some tips:

1. You are passing a string ([str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)) to the `count_numbers()` function, and when you iterate over a string, you always get strings back, and not `int`s, as you are expecting
2. Even if you did somehow get an `int`, your `if` statement would not work, because `i` would not be equal to "`int`", it would be equal to some *value* of *type* int. In that case, you would probably want to change the condition to something like `if isinstance(i, int)`
3. But since you always get strings when you iterate over the contents of a string, you can instead use the str method [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check if the contents of the string is a digit (`i.isdigit()`)
4. Then there's an issue with your dictionary handling...you have a few options...

### Dictionary Handling

1. Check if `i` is in the dictionary (as you are doing), and if so, retrieve its value and increment - if it isn't in the dictionary, set to 0
2. Use the dict's [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method instead of subscripts (`dictionary[i]`), because `get()` doesn't throw an exception if the item does not exist *and* it lets you pass an optional second parameter which is the default value to return if it doesn't exist (`0`) - then just increment and put it back: `dictionary[i] = dictionary.get(i, 0) + 1` (for clarity/readability, you may want to break this into three lines - get, increment, set)

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_numbers(text):
    # Initialize a new dictionary.
    dictionary = {}
    for i in text:
        if i.isnumeric():
            if i in dictionary:
                dictionary[i] = dictionary[i]+1
            else:
                dictionary[i] = 1
    return dictionary
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).